# Speeding up a (slow) huge wordpress database

Tags: php, mysql, performance, wordpress

I'm testing out a new project which involves the use of a wordpress installation which has over 1.5 million posts, generally the post content/title is only a line or two - so quite short.

I've already got the highly recommended W3-cache plugin, which helps a lot - but when you first land on a page it takes a good 40-60 to load and generate a cache of it, and with a site that contains over 1 million posts I'm guessing having them all cached is going to be a disaster - as only about 5% of these will be viewed on a regular basis.

Below is what's going on for a standard build of a post, is there anything I can do to change/speed up the obvious bottle neck? I'm not even sure what the JOIN is doing? surely all that needs to happen is get post by ID. The query that's taking so long looks like it's a query to show a number of posts and order them based on metadata - which I don't need on the post page?

```
 [5] => Array
    (
        [0] =>  SELECT   wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id) WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish') AND (wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'wpfp_favorites' ) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_postmeta.meta_value+0 ASC LIMIT 0, 1
        [1] => 43.2097918987
        [2] => require, require_once, include, get_header, locate_template, load_template, require_once, wp_head, do_action, call_user_func_array, start_post_rel_link, get_boundary_post_rel_link, get_boundary_post, get_posts, WP_Query->query, WP_Query->get_posts, W3_Db->query
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [0] => SELECT p.* FROM wp_posts AS p  WHERE p.post_date < '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND p.post_type = 'post' AND p.post_status = 'publish'  ORDER BY p.post_date DESC LIMIT 1
        [1] => 7.29560852051E-5
        [2] => require, require_once, include, get_header, locate_template, load_template, require_once, wp_head, do_action, call_user_func_array, adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head, adjacent_posts_rel_link, get_adjacent_post_rel_link, get_adjacent_post, W3_Db->query
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [0] => SELECT p.* FROM wp_posts AS p  WHERE p.post_date > '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND p.post_type = 'post' AND p.post_status = 'publish'  ORDER BY p.post_date ASC LIMIT 1
        [1] => 1.78813934326E-5
        [2] => require, require_once, include, get_header, locate_template, load_template, require_once, wp_head, do_action, call_user_func_array, adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head, adjacent_posts_rel_link, get_adjacent_post_rel_link, get_adjacent_post, W3_Db->query
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [0] => SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'theme_mods_twentyeleven' LIMIT 1
        [1] => 1.00135803223E-5
        [2] => require, require_once, include, get_header, locate_template, load_template, require_once, wp_head, do_action, call_user_func_array, _custom_background_cb, get_background_image, get_theme_mod, get_theme_mods, get_option, W3_Db->query
    )

[9] => Array
    (
        [0] => SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'mods_Twenty Eleven' LIMIT 1
        [1] => 8.82148742676E-6
        [2] => require, require_once, include, get_header, locate_template, load_template, require_once, wp_head, do_action, call_user_func_array, _custom_background_cb, get_background_image, get_theme_mod, get_theme_mods, get_option, W3_Db->query
    )

[10] => Array
    (
        [0] => SELECT t.*, tt.* FROM wp_terms AS t INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON tt.term_id = t.term_id INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships AS tr ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id WHERE tt.taxonomy IN ('post_format') AND tr.object_id IN (1034759) ORDER BY t.name ASC
        [1] => 1.31130218506E-5
        [2] => require, require_once, include, get_header, locate_template, load_template, require_once, body_class, get_body_class, get_post_format, get_the_terms, wp_get_object_terms, W3_Db->query
    )

[11] => Array
    (
        [0] => SELECT DISTINCT post_author FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish' LIMIT 2
        [1] => 1.31130218506E-5
        [2] => require, require_once, include, get_header, locate_template, load_template, require_once, body_class, get_body_class, apply_filters, call_user_func_array, twentyeleven_body_classes, is_multi_author, W3_Db->query
    )

[12] => Array
    (
        [0] => SELECT * FROM wp_posts  WHERE (post_type = 'page' AND post_status = 'publish')  AND ( ID <> 1232798 )    ORDER BY menu_order,wp_posts.post_title ASC
        [1] => 1.00135803223E-5
        [2] => require, require_once, include, get_header, locate_template, load_template, require_once, wp_nav_menu, call_user_func, wp_page_menu, wp_list_pages, get_pages, W3_Db->query
    )

[13] => Array
    (
        [0] => SELECT * FROM wp_users WHERE ID = 4031 LIMIT 1
        [1] => 2.00271606445E-5
        [2] => require, require_once, include, the_post, WP_Query->the_post, setup_postdata, get_userdata, W3_Db->query
    )

[14] => Array
    (
        [0] => SELECT t.*, tt.* FROM wp_terms AS t INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON tt.term_id = t.term_id INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships AS tr ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id WHERE tt.taxonomy IN ('post_tag') AND tr.object_id IN (1034759) ORDER BY t.name ASC
        [1] => 1.78813934326E-5
        [2] => require, require_once, include, get_template_part, locate_template, load_template, require, post_class, get_post_class, get_the_tags, get_the_terms, wp_get_object_terms, W3_Db->query
    )

[15] => Array
    (
        [0] => SELECT * FROM wp_comments  WHERE comment_approved = '1' AND comment_post_ID = 1034759 ORDER BY comment_date_gmt ASC 
        [1] => 2.09808349609E-5
        [2] => require, require_once, include, comments_template, get_comments, WP_Comment_Query->query, W3_Db->query
    )

[16] => Array
    (
        [0] => SELECT post_id, meta_value, post_status FROM wp_postmeta LEFT JOIN wp_posts ON post_id=wp_posts.ID WHERE post_status='publish' AND meta_key='wpfp_favorites' AND meta_value > 0 ORDER BY ROUND(meta_value) DESC LIMIT 0, 5
        [1] => 1.50203704834E-5
        [2] => require, require_once, include, get_sidebar, locate_template, load_template, require_once, dynamic_sidebar, call_user_func_array, wpfp_widget_view, wpfp_list_most_favorited, W3_Db->query
    )
```

Regardless of the above question, I'm on shared hosting at the momment - so obviously it's not going to cut it, what I want to ask is if you where running this sort of site - what sort of server specs/hosting plan would you be looking at to handle this size of installation? With a few thouand vistors to start per week moving up.

Comment: You can avoid `select *` and replace with `select a, b`

Comment: could you explain a bit more? not sure exactly what you mean

Comment: this is not helpful, I suggest you include the execution plan results (if you know what I mean)

Answer (score 4):

1) Use mysqltuner on WAMP (you can't install on shared hosting without root) to tune MySQL and change query cache, memory, etc. Will make a huge difference on WAMP and the eventual live server. https://github.com/rackerhacker/MySQLTuner-perl

2) Be sure to delete post/page revisions from the database. WP can store many revisions that greatly impact DB speed. I've seen DB sizes drop 90% after deleting post/page revisions.

Run as SQL query in phpmyadmin to delete revisions; change table prefix as necessary:

`DELETE a,b,c
FROM wp_posts a
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships b ON (a.ID = b.object_id)
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta c ON (a.ID = c.post_id)
WHERE a.post_type = 'revision'`

Then optimize all tables. And then add

`define ('WP_POST_REVISIONS', FALSE);`

near the top of wp-config.php (somewhere after the opening `<?php ...` ) to disable future revisions.

3) Increase memory for php and WP for better performance:

Edit the memory_limit line in your php.ini to 128M:

`memory_limit = 128M;`

Or add this line at the top of your .htaccess file:

`php_value memory_limit 128M`

If that doesn't work or throws an error, add this line near the top of your wp-config.php file right after the opening  `<?php`

`define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '128M');`

4) On the final VPS, configure http.conf for performance and possibly use different box for the MySQL server itself.

Comment: Do NOT use the DELETE SQL query above on a such large database! Most likely will break useful relations in database. Backup your database first at least.

Answer (score 2):

Shared host obviously hit the limit of performance. Problem is insufficient hardware, not the queries themselves, so what you'll have to do is get a dedicated machine for yourself. Bottleneck here seems to be MySQL which is usually disk bound, but if your site is about to grow really large I'd start preparing somewhat different architecture with load balancers for HTTP and a powerful machine for MySQL (I think that i7 with 12 gigs of ram isn't too expensive and I'd use that for the MySQL server if you're going with monolithic data-store).

Comment: Thanks I'll fire it up on a dedi and see how it effects the load times - appreciate your quick reply.

Comment: I'd set it up on a local machine before deciding which dedicated one to get. Use AB (ApacheBenchmark) to see how your site behaves under certain load conditions. Also remember that all software you got installed - from php and apache to mysql - has to be configured properly to work under load.

Comment: Cheers - Hmm, well I've got it setup on WAMP but it takes 3 times as long on my own machine win7/4gb/2.5ghz. Any idea why this would be?