# Speeding Up Large Wordpress Database queries

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, scaling

Wanted to get some advice on speeding up a large wordpress directory website that uses a bunch of queries to filter posts by price, weight, height, etc....

Currently, all the posts data are being stored as post meta. I am on a dedicated server, still slow. Was thinking that moving the post meta data to newly created columns in the regular posts table may speed it up? How do large sites query large databases with a number of filters without shutting down the browser?

Any suggestions (other than dont use WP, lol) are greatly appreciated. Or any resources/articles would be great too as I want to learn and build this myself.

Thanks

Comment: those columns indexed?

Comment: @wayne: Indexing is *not* universal cure for performance!

Comment: Hi, you're expected to show research efforts when posting a question (see [ask]). I'd suggest you dig into [wordpress.se] and [dba.se], then read each site [FAQ] and post in the most appropriate (cross-posting is not encouraged).

Comment: REFER THIS LINK FOR BETTER UNDERSTANDING

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172342/speeding-up-a-slow-huge-wordpress-database

Comment: Using caching will solve your performance slowdown, there is plenty of information out there, also plugins.

Comment: caching is not a solution as this content is not static and always changing.

Comment: Tried any caching plugins?